# python/kivy : set dynamically value on on_touch_down event in TextInput from treeView

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I have two files `test1.py` and `test1.kv`. There are a `+Add more` button.When click on `+Add More` button then row add dynamic.
I added treeView on `TextInput`.But now i am confused that how to put selected treeView value(`self.text`) in current TextBox because every `TextBox` added dynamic so i don't know how to set selected `treeView` value in current `TextBox`

## test1.py

```
import kivy

kivy.require('1.9.0')  # replace with your current kivy version !
import sqlite3 as lite
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import BooleanProperty, ListProperty, StringProperty, ObjectProperty, NumericProperty
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.uix.treeview import TreeView, TreeViewLabel, TreeViewNode
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

Window.size = (450, 525)


class TreeviewNumber(Popup):
    treeview = ObjectProperty(None)
    tv = ObjectProperty(None)
    h = NumericProperty(0)


    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(TreeviewNumber, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.tv = TreeView(root_options=dict(text=""),
                       hide_root=False,
                       indent_level=4)

        rows = [('One'), ('Two'), ('Three')]

        tree = []

        for r in rows:
            tree.append({'node_id': r, 'children': []})

        for branch in tree:
            populate_tree_view(self.tv, None, branch)
        #self.remove_widgets()
        self.treeview.add_widget(self.tv)
        Clock.schedule_once(self.update, 1)

    def remove_widgets(self):
        for child in [child for child in self.treeview.children]:
            self.treeview.remove_widget(child)

    def update(self, *args):
        self.h = len([child for child in self.tv.children]) * 24

def populate_tree_view(tree_view_city, parent, node):

    if parent is None:
        tree_node = tree_view_city.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True))
    else:
        tree_node = tree_view_city.add_node(TreeViewLabel(text=node['node_id'],
                                                     is_open=True), parent)

    for child_node in node['children']:
        populate_tree_view(tree_view_city, tree_node, child_node)

class TreeViewLabel(Label, TreeViewNode):
    pass

class display(Screen):

    def add_more(self):
        self.ids.rows.add_row()

    def insert_value(self):
        #print(Row().id)
        w = Row()
        print(w.ids.state.text)



class Row(BoxLayout):
    button_text = StringProperty("")
    state = ObjectProperty('')

    popupNumber = ObjectProperty(None)
    popup_number = ObjectProperty(None)

    def display_number(self,instance):
        if self.popupNumber is None:
            # if self.popupAccountCity is None:
            self.popupNumber = TreeviewNumber()
            self.popupNumber.popup_number = self
        self.popupNumber.open()


class Rows(BoxLayout):
    orientation = "vertical"
    row_count = 0
    button_text = StringProperty("")

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Rows, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.add_row()

    def add_row(self):
        self.row_count += 1
        self.add_widget(Row(button_text=str(self.row_count),id=str("test"+str(self.row_count))))


class test(App):

    def build(self):
        self.root = Builder.load_file('test1.kv')
        return self.root

if __name__ == '__main__':
    test().run()
```

## test1.kv

```
<Row>:
    state : state
    orientation: "horizontal"
    spacing: 0, 5

    Button:
        text: root.button_text
        size_hint_x: .2

    TextInput:
        #text : root.id
        size_hint_x: .8
        id : state
        on_focus: root.display_number(self)



display:

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        padding : 20, 20

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Button:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "+Add More"
                valign: 'bottom'
                on_press: root.add_more()


        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .2
                text: "SN"
                valign: 'bottom'

            Label:
                size_hint_x: .8
                text: "Value"
                valign: 'bottom'


        Rows:
            id: rows

        BoxLayout:
            orientation: "horizontal"
            padding : 10, 0
            spacing: 10, 10
            size_hint: .5, .7
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y':.25}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release:
                    root.insert_value()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<TreeviewNumber>:
    treeview: treeview
    title: "Select Number"
    title_size: 17
    title_font: "Verdana"
    #pos_hint: {'x': .62, 'y': .55}
    size_hint: .5, .5
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout
        orientation: "vertical"

        ScrollView:
            size_hint: 1, .9
            BoxLayout:
                size_hint_y: None
                id: treeview
                #height: root.h
                #rooot: root

        GridLayout:
            cols : 2
            row_default_height: '20dp'
            size_hint: .5, 0.2
            pos_hint: {'x': .25, 'y': 1}

            Button:
                text: 'Ok'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

            Button:
                text: 'Cancel'
                on_release: root.dismiss()

<TreeViewLabel>:
    text_size: self.size
    height: 24
    on_touch_down:
        print(self.text)
```

Comment: what is the name of the file 'test.py'? if so it may be running py.test or uniytest

Comment: @mosheslavin thanks for reply. I have updated file name.sorry for inconvenience